# Laravel, db:seed, MySQL, PHP date()

Tags: php, mysql

PHP, MySQL and Apache are all on the same server i.e. localhost Ubuntu.

System:

```
$ php -r 'echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."\n";';
2015-07-04 16:47:24
```

mysql server:

```
SELECT NOW(); // 2015-07-04 16:47:24`

DESCRIBE users
# Field, Type, Null, Key, Default, Extra
'created_at', 'datetime', 'NO', '', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', ''
'updated_at', 'datetime', 'NO', '', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', ''
```

PHP
`/etc/php5/cli/php.ini`

```
[Date]
; Defines the default timezone used by the date functions
; http://php.net/date.timezone
date.timezone = "Europe/London"

; http://php.net/date.default-latitude
;date.default_latitude = 31.7667

; http://php.net/date.default-longitude
;date.default_longitude = 35.2333

; http://php.net/date.sunrise-zenith
;date.sunrise_zenith = 90.583333

; http://php.net/date.sunset-zenith
;date.sunset_zenith = 90.583333
```

Why then does:

`$ php artisan db:seed`

using:

```
class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
 /**
  * Run the database seeds.
  *
  * @return void
  */
 public function run()
 {
    Model::unguard();

    // $this->call(UserTableSeeder::class);

    DB::table('users')->insert([
        'name' => str_random(10),
        'email' => str_random(10).'@gmail.com',
        'password' => bcrypt('secret'),
        'created_at' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s"),
        'updated_at' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s")
    ]);



    Model::reguard();
 }
}
```

insert records into the database only with the dates an hour behind? See:

[image]

It's a mystery.

More info:

```
$ php -i | grep 'Loaded Configuration File'
Loaded Configuration File => /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
```

And:

```
$ timedatectl
  Local time: Sun 2015-07-05 07:14:31 BST
  Universal time: Sun 2015-07-05 06:14:31 UTC
    RTC time: Sun 2015-07-05 06:14:31
   Time zone: Europe/London (BST, +0100)
  NTP enabled: yes
 NTP synchronized: yes
 RTC in local TZ: no
  DST active: yes
 Last DST change: DST began at
              Sun 2015-03-29 00:59:59 GMT
              Sun 2015-03-29 02:00:00 BST
 Next DST change: DST ends (the clock jumps one hour backwards) at
              Sun 2015-10-25 01:59:59 BST
              Sun 2015-10-25 01:00:00 GMT
```

Comment: can you please check the path of php.ini file being used from the phpinfo() output?

Comment: Check your system time with the command: timedatectl. I think that one is wrong.